# Making a pandas df using lists

Tags: python, list, pandas

I am trying to use a list to create a pandas dataframe but the list I have is not the way it is normally required to setup a pandas dataframe. I can provide an example below to show what I would be talking about.

```
 listA <- ['Type', 'Style', 'Size', 'Lot Size', 'Age', 'Taxes']

 listB <- ['Detached', 'Bungalow', 'Contact Us', '\n\n25 x 100 Feet \n', 
 'Contact Us', '$3,030 /yr']
```

Using the above list, I am trying to create a pandas df as per below

```
 Type      Style     Size         Lot Size               Age           Taxes 
 Detached  Bungalow  Contact Us   \n\n25 x 100 Feet \n   Contact Us    $3,030 /yr
```

I know the conventional way is to use pd.DataFrame(colname, columns=['data']) but in this case, the lists being generated is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list of lists for data parameter and for columns names `listB`:

```
listA = ['Type', 'Style', 'Size', 'Lot Size', 'Age', 'Taxes']
listB = ['Detached', 'Bungalow', 'Contact Us', '\n\n25 x 100 Feet \n', 'Contact Us', '$3,030 /yr']    
df = pd.DataFrame([listB], columns=listA) 
print (df)
       Type     Style        Size              Lot Size         Age  \
0  Detached  Bungalow  Contact Us  \n\n25 x 100 Feet \n  Contact Us   

        Taxes  
0  $3,030 /yr
```

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying the data and columns. The params will be like below

```
>>> x = ['Type', 'Style', 'Size', 'Lot Size', 'Age', 'Taxes']
>>> y = ['Detached', 'Bungalow', 'Contact Us', '\n\n25 x 100 Feet \n', 'Contact Us', '$3,030 /yr']    
>>> pd.DataFrame(data=[y],columns=x)
       Type     Style        Size              Lot Size         Age  \
0  Detached  Bungalow  Contact Us  \n\n25 x 100 Feet \n  Contact Us   

        Taxes  
0  $3,030 /yr
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(listA,listB)))
```